# Why Turning ANSI_WARNINGS Off Causes Error Updating Col Used as a Source of a Computed Col?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-standard, computed-column

I have a stored procedure that updates the source column used in a computed column.

That stored procedure has `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;`.

When the procedure executes, and tries to update the source column, the following error message is received:

> `Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Procedure my_PROC, Line XX
>    UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 
>    'ANSI_WARNINGS'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views 
>    and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query 
>    notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.`

The error stops when either:

1. We stop turning `ANSI_WARNINGS` off, or;
2. The source column (the one used in deriving the computed column) is removed from the update statement.

There is one clustered index and one non-clustered index, both on columns which are not involved in any way in the computed column definition.

What is it about the column being used in a computed column that causes this error?

Comment: Do you have a filtered index on that table?

Comment: No, there is a clustered index on a column which is not involved in any way in the computed column definition, and 1 non-clustered index, also not involved in the computed column in any way. I will add this info to the question

Comment: Do you have any indexed views pointing to this table?

Comment: This is exactly what [the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175088%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says.

Comment: Computed column created as persisted? Would cause this behaviour. It's not in the error message but is in the documentation as per Erik's link.